# Subplots visualization in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, visualization

How would one visualize several subplots from one table, using the Databricks visualization function? I've seen this in a presentation and can't figure out how to make it work.

This is how it looks like :

- [the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7u7O.png)
- [the plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nDGj.png)